# I don't understand very good the benefits of the salt and hashed password in the client side

Tags: security

I have readed this article:

https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm

It is said that in a web application, always it is needed to hash the password in the server to ensure that the hash is correct. But if the client hash the password and sends to the server, the server what to do is hash the password, so how can the server hash the password if what it receives from the client is the hashed password?

The other doubt that I have is the basic steps that it is needed to do:

- Retrieve the user's salt and hash from the database.
- Prepend the salt to the given password and hash it using the same hash function.
- Compare the hash of the given password with the hash from the database. If they match, the password is correct. Otherwise, the password is incorrect.

Well, the server get the password from the client, use the salt with the password from the client, hashes it and compare with the hashed password from the database. Well, how the salt is always the same for this user and it get from the database, if a middle man get the password, can use this password and authenticate in the database, because the server will use the salt and get the same hashed password. So no matter if it is the real user or the middle man, the server allow the access.

Another option is if the server receive the hashed password, it just needs to get the hash from the database, so it avoids to hash, saving resources. Then the client instead of send the password, send the hashed password and the server compare this hashed password from the client with the hash of the database. here, a middle man can get the hashed password too and use it to authenticate. At the end, is the same that if the user send the password.

I don't see the benefit to salt and hash the password, because if a middle man attack the connection, he can authenticate in the database. So I think that the important it is to ensure that the connection is safe, and then is the same to send the password in plain text, because the connection is secure. But perhaps I don't understand something because I know that salt and hash the password it is a common practice.

The only real benefit that I see to hash the password if one attacker get access to the database, because he can not get the password from the hashed password, but if a attacker access to the database, he can get access to all the information, so I guess the less important data is the password.

For that reason I am wondering, Is it not enough with a secure connection? because if an attacker can access to the connection, then he can access to the password and can authenticate in the server. If the attacker can not get access to the connection, then why to hash the password in the server? Is waste resources to hash the password because is a hard process.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash algorithms are asymetric, which means that you can generate the hash but going from a hash to the login credentials is much harder.

Keeping the password in an unclear form in the database prevents bad-intended people who can access it to get the clear password and authenticate as the user.

Moreover, it's not by accessing the hashed password record in the database that would allow an attacker to steal the account but by accessing **the server source code to determine how the password is generated** and then be able to regenerate it.

Considering that firebug for example allows you to access the client source code, you don't want to perform the password generation on the client side.

PS : If you implement SSL and HTTPS, then the packets of your request are encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

We need salts. When you try to login, you hash your password client-side and send the hash to the server. They compare your hash to their hash (they also still have your password in plaintext).

What if an attacker captures your hash in transit? A good hash algorithm won't let them go from the hash back to the password, but hackers can use rainbow tables... They can try tons of passwords until they find a password with the same hash.

To stop this from happening - from the attacker from finding your password - we use a random salt. We add some random stuff onto your password before we hash it so that the hash isn't the same as the hash for your password. We send the new hash along to the server with the salt in plaintext. The server adds the salt to their copy of your password and they hash it. If the hash matches what you sent them, you login.

But since the salt is always changing, an attacker will have a hard time cracking your password.

Comment: But if you sent the hash from the  client and the server compare this has with the hash in database, the attacker does not need to know the password, only need to send the hashed password. And why the server has the plain text password, if what the sever compares is the hashed password?

Comment: The salt makes the hash different. So if they got the hash, it wouldn't be good for long. Tomorrow, we would have a new salt and a new hash.